# django admin inline formset override save

Tags: django, django-admin

I have  a model that looks like this:

```
class ProjectImage(models.Model):
    big_thumb = ThumbnailField(upload_to='profiles', size=(500, 500))
    med_thumb = ThumbnailField(upload_to='profiles', size=(300, 300))
    small_thumb = ThumbnailField(upload_to='profiles', size=(100, 100))
```

I associate ProjectImage with a Project as a TabularInline.  In the admin, I'd like to be able to say if the medium and/or small thumbnails were not provided, use the same image as the big thumbnail.  However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to specify this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options in this case, you can either over-ride `ProjectImage`'s save defintion and have it copy `big_thumb` to `med_thumb` and `small_thumb` if they are None, or just create a simple model definition to display each field.

```
def get_med_thumb_url(self):
    if self.med_thumb is None:
         return self.big_thumb.url

    return self.med_thumb.url
```

And do the same for `small_thumb` That keeps you from fidgeting with the save method and having to copy things over and waste space.

I can't remember if `ImageField` has a `get_FOO_url` type definition but if it does you could always over-ride that.

Comment: Can I still override ProjectImage's save method even though it's an Inline form?

Comment: I don't see why not. It still has to be saved. :)